# SoapServer with WSDL not working as wanted

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

So first of all I am trying to make a SOAP web service which will respond to a Soap Request the soap request incomming is:

> RZS:notificeerOverZaak_Di01

and the output should be

> StuF:Bv03

Instead the output is:

> ns1:notificeerOverZaak_Di01Reply

This is the index file, the functions are added here and this is were the server is set up.

```
<?php
//session starts, and error reproting
header('content-type: text/xml');
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('initialize.php');

function notificeerOverZaak_Di01($stuurgegevens = null,$melding = null,$object = null){
    $data = array(
        "Stuurgegevens" => json_encode($stuurgegevens),
        "Melding" => json_encode($melding),
        "Object" => json_encode($object),
        "Received" => true

    );

    DatabaseController::Environment('c3-api-king')
        ->table('message_received')
        ->insert($data);
    //XML laden
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->load('Bv03.xml');
    $xml_string = $xml->saveXML();
    DatabaseController::Environment('c3-api-king')
    ->table('reply_sent')
    ->insert(array('reply'=>$xml_string));
    $xml_string = trim(str_replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>', '', $xml_string));
    return $xml_string;

}

$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("test/rzs0310/rzsberichten/rzs0310_ontvangAsynchroon_rzsberichten.wsdl","StUF:Bv03");
$server->methodreturnisliteralxml = true;
$server->register(
    "notificeerOverZaak_Di01"
);

$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

The WSDL File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2015 sp2 (http://www.altova.com) by Johan Boer (Kwaliteits Instituut Nederlandse Gemeenten) -->
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:StUF="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301" xmlns:ZKN="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsi="http://ws-i.org/schemas/conformanceClaim/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:RZS="http://www.stufstandaarden.nl/koppelvlak/rzs0310" name="StUF-ZKN0310" targetNamespace="http://www.stufstandaarden.nl/koppelvlak/rzs0310">
    <import namespace="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301" location="../../0301/stuf0301_types.wsdl"/>
    <documentation>
        <xs:documentation>
        Dit document definieert de webservices voor het portType OntvangAsynchroon voor het Regie-Zaak services koppelvlak.         
        </xs:documentation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <StUF:onderdeel>http://www.stufstandaarden.nl/koppelvlak/rzs0310</StUF:onderdeel>
            <StUF:patch>-</StUF:patch>
            <StUF:patchdatum>-</StUF:patchdatum>
            <StUF:schemaversie>0</StUF:schemaversie>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </documentation>
    <types>
        <xs:schema>
            <xs:import namespace="http://www.stufstandaarden.nl/koppelvlak/rzs0310" schemaLocation="rzs0310_msg_rzsberichten.xsd"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="notificeerOverZaak_Di01">
        <part name="body" element="RZS:notificeerOverZaak_Di01"/>
    </message>
    <message name="initieerNotificeerOverZaak_Di01">
        <part name="body" element="RZS:initieerNotificeerOverZaak_Di01"/>
    </message>
    <message name="overdragenZaak_Di01">
        <part name="body" element="RZS:overdragenZaak_Di01"/>
    </message>
    <message name="overdragenZaak_Du01">
        <part name="body" element="RZS:overdragenZaak_Du01"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="OntvangAsynchroon">
        <documentation>
        Dit portType ondersteunt als operaties alle asynchrone berichten gedefinieerd binnen het sectormodel
    </documentation>
        <operation name="Bv03">
            <input message="StUF:Bv03"/>
            <output message="StUF:Bv03"/>
            <fault name="fout" message="StUF:Fo03"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Fo03">
            <input message="StUF:Fo03"/>
            <output message="StUF:Bv03"/>
            <fault name="fout" message="StUF:Fo03"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="notificeerOverZaak">
            <input message="RZS:notificeerOverZaak_Di01"/>
            <output message="StUF:Bv03"/>
            <fault name="fout" message="StUF:Fo03"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="initieerNotificeerOverZaak">
            <input message="RZS:initieerNotificeerOverZaak_Di01"/>
            <output message="StUF:Bv03"/>
            <fault name="fout" message="StUF:Fo03"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="overdragenZaak">
            <input message="RZS:overdragenZaak_Di01"/>
            <output message="StUF:Bv03"/>
            <fault name="fout" message="StUF:Fo03"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="bevestigOverdragenZaak">
            <input message="RZS:overdragenZaak_Du01"/>
            <output message="StUF:Bv03"/>
            <fault name="fout" message="StUF:Fo03"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="SOAPOntvangAsynchroon" type="RZS:OntvangAsynchroon">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
        <operation name="Bv03">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301/Bv03"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="fout">
                <soap:fault name="fout" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Fo03">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301/Fo03" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="fout">
                <soap:fault name="fout" use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="notificeerOverZaak">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/rzs/0310/notificeerOverZaak" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="fout">
                <soap:fault name="fout" use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="initieerNotificeerOverZaak">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/rzs/0310/initieerNotificeerOverZaak" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="fout">
                <soap:fault name="fout" use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="overdragenZaak">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/rzs/0310/overdragenZaak" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="fout">
                <soap:fault name="fout" use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="bevestigOverdragenZaak">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/rzs/0310/bevestigOverdragenZaak" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="fout">
                <soap:fault name="fout" use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="OntvangAsynchroon">
        <documentation>     
    Hieronder wordt de concreet aan te roepen service voor het ontvangen van asynchrone ZKN0310-berichten gedefinieerd. 
        </documentation>
        <port name="OntvangAsynchroon" binding="RZS:SOAPOntvangAsynchroon">
            <documentation>
                <wsi:Claim xmlns:wsi="http://ws-i.org/schemas/conformanceClaim/" conformsTo="http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1"/>
            </documentation>
            <soap:address location="http://87.250.154.26:7080/opentunnel/00000001001877045000/50422931/AllTypes" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

The xml document we are returning in the end of the function is:

```
<StUF:Bv03Bericht xmlns:StUF="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ZKN="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310" xmlns:BG="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301 stuf0301.xsd">
  <StUF:stuurgegevens>
    <StUF:berichtcode>Bv03</StUF:berichtcode>
    <StUF:zender>
      <StUF:organisatie>C3group</StUF:organisatie>
      <StUF:applicatie>C3groupApi</StUF:applicatie>
      <StUF:gebruiker/>
    </StUF:zender>
    <StUF:ontvanger>
      <StUF:organisatie>KING</StUF:organisatie>
      <StUF:applicatie>STP</StUF:applicatie>
      <StUF:gebruiker/>
    </StUF:ontvanger>
    <StUF:referentienummer>Di01</StUF:referentienummer>
    <StUF:tijdstipBericht>20161115145026</StUF:tijdstipBericht>
    <StUF:crossRefnummer/>
  </StUF:stuurgegevens>
</StUF:Bv03Bericht>
```

The reply at the moment is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:notificeerOverZaak_Di01Response xmlns:ns1="http://www.stufstandaarden.nl/koppelvlak/rzs0310">
         <StUF:Bv03Bericht xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301 stuf0301.xsd" xmlns:StUF="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ZKN="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310" xmlns:BG="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310">
            <StUF:stuurgegevens>
               <StUF:berichtcode>Bv03</StUF:berichtcode>
               <StUF:zender>
                  <StUF:organisatie>C3group</StUF:organisatie>
                  <StUF:applicatie>C3groupApi</StUF:applicatie>
                  <StUF:gebruiker/>
               </StUF:zender>
               <StUF:ontvanger>
                  <StUF:organisatie>KING</StUF:organisatie>
                  <StUF:applicatie>STP</StUF:applicatie>
                  <StUF:gebruiker/>
               </StUF:ontvanger>
               <StUF:referentienummer>Di01</StUF:referentienummer>
               <StUF:tijdstipBericht>20161115145026</StUF:tijdstipBericht>
               <StUF:crossRefnummer/>
            </StUF:stuurgegevens>
         </StUF:Bv03Bericht>
      </ns1:notificeerOverZaak_Di01Response>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The only thing wrong with the above is the  shouldnt be there.